# How to make regex for phone number start with 60xxxxxxx

Tags: javascript, regex

sorry i know this question might duplicated but i'm really bad in regex, hope someone could help to fix it. How i can apply this regex in my javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

```
^6?01\d{8}$
```

My current coding.

```
function phoneNumber()  
{

  var mobile = document.mainform.HP_NO.value;

    //need condition here if phone number does not match with the regex given 
         alert("Not a valid Phone Number.");
         document.mainform.HP_NO.value = "";
         document.mainform.HP_NO.focus();
         return false;
    ///

     return true;
}  

<input type="text"  class="input-name" name="HP_NO" placeholder="e.g (60121234567)" onblur="if(value=='') value = '';phoneNumber();" onfocus="if(value=='') maxlength="11" onPaste="return false"/>
```

Comment: it is simple just use like this 60\d{8}

Answer (score 4):

1. *How to make regex for phone number start with 60xxxxxxx*

Your `regex` should be

```
^60\d{8}$
```

to check if number *starts with* `60`

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Starts with
- `60`: Matches literal `60`
- `\d`: Matches any number/digit
- `{8}`: Matches 8 times the previous group
- `$` : Ends with

**Visual Representation**

[image]

---

2. *How i can apply this regex in my javascript.*

You can use [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if `string` satisfies `regex`.

```
var regex = /^60\d{8}$/;
if (regex.test(mobile) === false) {
    alert("Not a valid Phone Number.");
    ....
}
```